# When do you contact ATC when departing from a non-towered airport into class D controlled airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, airspace

I had this question posed to me the other day and I wanted to make sure I responded correctly.

When do you contact ATC when departing from a non-towered airport into class D controlled airspace?

This is the situation where the uncontrolled airport sits under the Class D shelf.

Answer (score 8):

Class D is usually a cylinder so there's no shelf to be underneath; I'm assuming you're asking about departing from an uncontrolled airport that's actually in class D, like this one (N96):

[image]

Because class D goes to the surface I'd try to contact ATC on the ground before departure if possible, either on a regular frequency or via an RCO. And it would be worth checking the Chart Supplement for any local rules.

Otherwise, [14 CFR 91.129](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=ecabe250da219842c0b8b8ec4d7476fd&n=14y2.0.1.3.10.2&r=SUBPART&ty=HTML%2523se14.2.91_1129#se14.2.91_1129) says you should contact ATC as soon as you can after departure:

> (2) Departing flight. Each person—
>
> [...]
>
> (ii) From a satellite airport without an operating control tower, must
>   establish and maintain two-way radio communications with the ATC
>   facility having jurisdiction over the Class D airspace area as soon as
>   practicable after departing.

There are some special cases like [KDTS](https://skyvector.com/airport/DTS/Destin-Executive-Airport) where you can't takeoff without contacting ATC first, but it's in a special rules area.