# Does this chart show a heliport in class D airspace without a control tower?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airspace, class-d-airspace, helipad, klax

I was looking at the Los Angeles area on sky vector, and I noticed a tiny little triangular class D area right next to LAX. It shows that the height of the class D goes up to 2,500, but I couldn't see an airport in there, not even on the TAC.

Only if you click on "LA West Heli" on the top right on sky vector can you see that there is a heliport in that little area called "Chevron Refinery". On airnav, it says the identifier is 4CA6, and it says it does not have a control tower.

I have so many questions. Why is it class D if it has no control tower? Can a heliport even be class D? Why the actual heliport not appear on the sectional or even TAC? Can someone help me? :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this may have been addressed before on ASE-- hang on, looking--

Comment: Actually the class D is for the nearby hang gliding airport.  (Kidding).  The existence of a marked hang gliding site in Class D is rather "interesting", considering the language of Part 103.  I know it's basically a "bunny hill" training site and they never get more than a few wingspans high there.  I wonder if any special arrangements were made re permission for hang gliding, when the airspace was given the Class D designation?  Could be grounds for another ASE question there--

Comment: These links re a related question appear to also answer your question -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50109/34686, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/82909/34686 . Basically, the Class D airspace is controlled by LAX tower, not the heliport. It's possible that the Class D airspace designation would have still occurred even if the heliport were not there--see the similar chunk of Class D airspace a few miles to the north, which contains no heliport or airport.

Comment: thanks @quietflyer
What is the purpose of this class D airspace if it contains no airport?

Comment: Well, it's in a high-traffic area close to LAX.  The fine print in the lower right hand portion of the text associated with the second link in the comment above, mentions a mid-air collision (elsewhere) which heightened concerns about airspace near busy airports -- and also indicates that the intent was to make the airspace Class B eventually. Apparently it was easier to make it Class D first.

Comment: @StephenS -- the last part of yellow-highlighted text in this answer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50109/when-is-this-class-d-airspace-not-class-d-airspace/82909#82909 indicates that the intent is to make the airspace at LAX part of the Class B eventually-- as far as SEA goes, I'm not seeing new expansions to the class D there-- it seems all the Class D near SEA is actually associated w/ KRNT and KBFI as described on pp D-71 and D-72 here -- https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/order_7400.11E_2020.pdf -- last changed in '94-- or are you seeing something else?

Comment: @StephenS -- (continuing) -- I looked at https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/airspace_amendments/ and didn't see anything new near SEA --

Comment: @StephenS-- oops I forgot about my own ASE answer re SEA https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/75354/34686.  Here the Class D is designated as an "extension".  Last modified '94. It appears on pp D164-165 of the current document https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/order_7400.11E_2020.pdf.  Why they made it an "extension" here and not at LAX, who knows-- maybe they decided Class D "extensions" don't really fit the established pattern and shouldn't really exist.  Since the Class D at SEA has been there since '94, it doesn't look like they intend to ever convert it to part of the Cl. B

Comment: @StephenS -- re the "extension" question-- I guess part of the answer is contained in https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/75354/34686 -- "Each piece of Class D airspace at KLAX is described as part of a ring of Class D airspace that completely encircles KLAX. "  So that's why it's not an "extension", because it is described in such a way that it includes the airport itself.  It just happens to be superseded by the Class B almost everywhere, so only two slivers are left.  But as to why they did it that way at LAX and not at SEA, who knows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangular area you’re referring to is actually the LAX class D airspace.

The heliport itself is uncontrolled. It is not that uncommon for an uncontrolled heliport or airport to be within the surface area of a controlled airport. Departing aircraft are required to contact tower as soon as practical after takeoff, and arriving aircraft are told that landing is at their own risk.

Comment: Related: [When do you contact ATC when departing from a non-towered airport into class D controlled airspace?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43051/14897)

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/75354/34686